# How Amazon Athena selecting new files/records from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm adding files on Amazon S3 from time to time, and I'm using Amazon Athena to perform a query on these data and save it in another S3 bucket as CSV format (aggregated data), I'm trying to find way for Athena to select only new data (which not queried before by Athena), in order to optimize the cost and avoid data duplication.
I have tried to update the records after been selected by Athena, but update query not supported in Athena.
Is any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Athena does not keep track of files on S3, it only figures out what files to read when you run a query.

When planning a query Athena will look at the table metadata for the table location, list that location, and finally read all files that it finds during query execution. If the table is partitioned it will list the locations of all partitions that matches the query.

The only way to control which files Athena will read during query execution is to partition a table and ensure that queries match the partitions you want it to read.

One common way of reading only new data is to put data into prefixes on S3 that include the date, and create tables partitioned by date. At query time you can then filter on the last week, month, or other time period to limit the amount of data read.

You can find more information [about partitioning in the Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html).

Comment: It's also good to remind that you need to [repair your table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) to add new partitions to Glue Metadata.